# Strict standard errors since upgrade to PHP 5.4

Tags: php

My host forced me to upgrade from PHP 5.3 to 5.4 and now I get these errors :

```
PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be assigned by reference in /public_html/modules/mod_yj_newsflash5/yjme/headfiles.php on line 13 

PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method YJmeHelp::YJmeItems() should not be called statically in /public_html/modules/mod_yj_newsflash5/mod_yj_newsflash5.php on line 34 

PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be assigned by reference in public_html/modules/mod_yj_newsflash5/helper.php on line 22 

PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be assigned by reference in public_html/modules/mod_yj_newsflash5/helper.php on line 23 

PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be assigned by reference in public_html/modules/mod_yj_newsflash5/helper.php on line 27 

PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be assigned by reference in public_html/modules/mod_yj_newsflash5/helper.php on line 30 

PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be assigned by reference in public_html/modules/mod_yj_newsflash5/yjme/headfiles.php on line 13 

PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method YJmeHelp::YJmeItems() should not be called statically in public_html/modules/mod_yj_newsflash5/mod_yj_newsflash5.php on line 34 

PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be assigned by reference in public_html/modules/mod_yj_newsflash5/helper.php on line 22 

PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be assigned by reference in public_html/modules/mod_yj_newsflash5/helper.php on line 23 

PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be assigned by reference in public_html/modules/mod_yj_newsflash5/helper.php on line 27 

PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be assigned by reference in public_html/modules/mod_yj_newsflash5/helper.php on line 30
```

What does all this mean ?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using & (ampersand) symbol you should remove the symbol